# Error using getLoaderManager().initLoader

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Error using getLoaderManager().initLoader

```
public class CatalogActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private static final int PET_LOADER = 0;

    PetCursorAdapter mCursorAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CatalogActivity.this, EditorActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        ListView petListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        View emptyView = findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        petListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);

        mCursorAdapter = new PetCursorAdapter(this, null);
        petListView.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(PET_LOADER, null, this);
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qd1ls.png)
This is the image of the problem on Android Studio

Comment: What is the error saying? Please update the question.

Comment: Could you hover over the red line and tell what does it say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LoaderManager Class ti init Loader

```
LoaderManager.getInstance(this).initLoader(PET_LOADER, null, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `LoaderManager.getInstance(this).initLoader(0,null,this);`
instead of `getLoaderManager().initLoader(PET_LOADER, null, this);`